# FluentValidation client-side validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, fluentvalidation

I tried to use GreaterThen validator and it looks like it doesn't support client-side validation. Is there a list of FluentValidation validators which support client-side validation?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The list of validators supported on the client is on [this page](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=mvc&referringTitle=Documentation) and are as follows:

- NotNull/NotEmpty (required)
- Matches (regex)
- InclusiveBetween (range)
- CreditCard
- Email
- EqualTo (cross-property equality comparison)
- Length

Comment: Oh, how I missed it... Is there any specific reason why GreaterThan and similar validators are not supported on client-side?

Comment: @Idsa: Quoted from http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/discussions/256069: *"The only validators that are client-side enabled out of the box are those that directly correspond to MVC's built-in client-side validators."*

Answer (score 0):

So far i know there is no list, you could create your own client side validator so create that createrthen works also on client side

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[Form Helper](https://github.com/sinanbozkus/FormHelper)**. It adds client-side support to Fluent-Validation.

**Startup.cs**

```
services.AddFormHelper();
With configuration: (optional)

services.AddFormHelper(new FormHelperConfiguration
{
    CheckTheFormFieldsMessage = "Your custom message...",
    RedirectDelay = 6000,
    DebugMode = true
});
```

**View:**

```
var formConfig = new FormConfig(ViewContext)
{
    FormId = "ProductForm",
    FormTitle = "New Product",
    BeforeSubmit = "ProductFormBeforeSubmit", // optional
    Callback = "ProductFormCallback" // optional,
};

// <form id="@formConfig.FormId" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Save"
// ...

@await Html.RenderFormScript(formConfig)
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost, FormValidator]
public IActionResult Save(FormViewModel viewModel)
```