# MVC Razor Conditional Validation with Data Annotation on drop down and radio button

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I am new to MVC Razor.  I have to implement conditional validation on a Dropdown selection and Radio button (using data annotations).  I have two conditions:

1. My dropdown contains three values: yes, no, and none.  If the user select "none" then only required validation should be applied on the remaining field like city and state.
2. I have two radio buttons, yes and no.  If the user selects no, then only required validation should be applied on remaining field like zipcode.

I have found many solutions, but none are ideal.  If you are a master of MVC Razor please provide me demo sample zip whatever I have explained above only.

Answer (score 1):

For cases with "inter-properties" validation, DataAnnotation is usually not the best (or clear, or easy to implement) tool.

Take a look at FluentValidation
http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/

And you will be able to write rules like (pseudoCode)

```
RuleFor(m => m.City)
      .NotNull()
      .When(m => m.<mydropdownName> == Conditions.None)
      .WithMessage("You must choose a city when you chosse none");
```

Comment: thanks for reply..but i do not know about  FluentValidation.please Provide me sample demo

Comment: @user1624306 Look at the url I gave, maybe ? There's a "documentation" tab, with fine examples.

Comment: it is client side validation?i want client side validation?

Comment: @user1624306 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6883488/fluentvalidation-client-side-validation