# Datetimepicker display format issue

Tags: google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap, datetime, datepicker, data-annotations

I am not sure if I am the only one having this issue on Chrome Browser but it is really annoying that I cannot fix it. I have done quite a bit of search here but nothing has helped.

First of all here is my ViewModel Data Annotation

```
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm}")]
    [DisplayName("Start Date")]
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
```

On the view I am using [datetimepicker bootstrap extension](http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)

When I am on the process of Creating the date I just select the date from the calander then I select the time as well. On the creating process there is no issue on Chrome and EI10. However, once the date has been created I go to edit mode to change the date. The date is displayed in dd/MM/yyy hh:mm format(example  18/03/2014 10:00) instead of yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm (2014-03-18 10:00). Without changing the date I click Update button on the page I get the validation error for the date fields.(See the screenshot) This is only in chrome browser. in EI10 everthing works fine. This is the first time that I am experiencing that something works on IE but not in Chrome :)

I have also set the datetimepicker date format to

```
$('.startdate').datetimepicker({ format: 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm' });
```

But still I cannot change the display format of the field to yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm. The last thing that comes in my mind that I will have to convert the format in the controler before it gets passed the view?  But I thought the ViewModel annotations is actually should be doing that for me or I am wrong ?

I found a line of code that people are suggesting for the issue

```
jQuery.validator.methods["date"] = function (value, element) { return true; }
```

I still couldn't get it work

[image]

Comment: Just in case you din't get it working, here's the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18565031/1678053