# HTML5 date of format dd/MMM/YYYY

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html

I'm having trouble using date of format dd/MMM/YYYY on MVC5 asp.net project. Mostly on Chrome, as it seem to only accept dates of format yyyy/mm/dd.

To normalize behavior across browsers, I'm using a jquery datetimepicker component.

I have tried many things, but Chrome is still saying that the date is not valid. Even after define the input as text instead of date.

Also even if I turn off validation for that particular component (data-val="false"), Chrome still insist on marking the date as invalid.

Model:

```
public class order 
{
    [Key]
    public int orderID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string comments { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MMM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = false)]
    [Display(Name = "Date of Shipping")]
    public DateTime date { get; set; }
}
```

View date input:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.date, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control datetimepicker" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.date, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Imports:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"/script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/jquery.datetimepicker.min.css" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js"></script>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.datetimepicker.setLocale('es');

    jQuery('#date').datetimepicker({
        format: 'd/M/Y',
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Having `[DataType(DataType.Date)]` and `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MMM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]` is pointless if your using a jquery datepicker (and then you can remove the `new { @type = "text" }`

Comment: If you getting a client side error, its because `jquery.validate` validates dates based on `MM/dd/yyyy` format. You need to reconfigure the validator to accept dates in your format

Comment: Remove `@type = "text"` - this attribute is unrelated. Also your datetimepicker format seems to be wrong - it should be `$('#date').datetimepicker({format : "DD/MMM/YYYY"})`. And then set the client-side validation with this: `$.validator.methods.date = function (value, element) { return this.optional(element) ||  $.datetimepicker.parseDate('DD/MMM/YYYY', value); }`

Comment: @StephenMuecke, have remoe DateType anotations and `new { @type = "text" }` as you said no needed.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto, format is fine, as I'm using datetimepicker from https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/, and is the proper format. for the validator method, parseDate does not exists, should I include a java script library or I'm missing something?

Comment: @atlus My bad, I don't know that you're using other `datetimepicker` than jquery has. `parseDate` is a method used with `Globalize.parseDate`, see this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18546971/mvc-4-how-to-validate-a-non-us-date-with-client-validation.

Answer (score 1):

I was finally able to fix the issue:

-Fisrt you need to add moment.js to your project, it can be added using NutGet manager, then reference on your pages:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/moment-with-locales.min.js")
```

Very important, if working with dates on non English format, you need to import moment-with-locales as if not, even after change locale it will stay as 'en'

-Then add following java script code:

```
$.datetimepicker.setDateFormatter({
   parseDate: function (date, format) {
       var d = moment(date, format);
       return d.isValid() ? d.toDate() : false;
},

formatDate: function (date, format) {
    return moment(date).format(format);
    }
});

$.validator.methods.date = function (value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || moment(value, "DD/MMM/YYYY", 'es').isValid();
}
```

-Also note that datetimepicker initialization changes as follows:

```
jQuery('#date').datetimepicker({
    format: 'DD/MMM/YYYY HH:mm',
    formatTime: 'HH:mm',
    formatDate: 'DD/MMM/YYYY'
});
```